# Some Spark Tasks In a Stage take much longer than others

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql query that look like this:

```
val stats = readings
  .join(stations, $"r.stationId" === $"i.stationId")
  .groupBy($"i.country", $"r.date")
  .agg(min($"r.temp").as("min"), max($"r.temp").as("max"), avg($"r.temp").as("avg"))
  .as[CountryTemperatureDistribution]
```

When I run this over my dataset some of the tasks in the longest running stage take far longer to run than others.  For example the summary in the spark ui is:

```
Index   ID  Executor ID     Launch Time     Duration    GC Time Input Sze / Rec     Write Time  Shuffle Write Size / Rec
2       5   0 / 10.1.0.6    12:36:38        12 s        1 s     14.4 MB / 9287283   2 s         3.7 MB / 138847     
3       6   2 / 10.1.0.4    12:36:38        17 s        2 s     0.0 B / 9273044     0.4 s       3.8 MB / 141888     
5       8   0 / 10.1.0.6    12:36:38        22 s        1 s     14.5 MB / 9064853   1 s         5.6 MB / 206393     
0       3   2 / 10.1.0.4    12:36:38        23 s        2 s     0.0 B / 9290667     0.3 s       4.1 MB / 157233     
6       9   2 / 10.1.0.4    12:36:38        23 s        2 s     0.0 B / 9233245     0.2 s       4.1 MB / 158441     
1       4   1 / 10.1.0.5    12:36:38        24 s        3 s     14.5 MB / 9289969   1 s         3.9 MB / 149370     
4       7   1 / 10.1.0.5    12:36:38        24 s        3 s     14.8 MB / 9250565   1 s         4.0 MB / 154438     
10      13  1 / 10.1.0.5    12:36:38        1.5 min     3 s     14.1 MB / 8734757   0.3 s       6.3 MB / 234829     
12      15  0 / 10.1.0.6    12:36:50        2.3 min     88 ms   7.3 MB / 4338998    0.5 s       4.8 MB / 177381     
9       12  2 / 10.1.0.4    12:36:38        3.1 min     2 s     0.0 B / 8242837     0.1 s       8.2 MB / 301212     
8       11  0 / 10.1.0.6    12:36:38        7.3 min     2 s     13.1 MB / 8346974   0.4 s       7.6 MB / 277488     
11      14  0 / 10.1.0.6    12:36:38        7.6 min     2 s     13.0 MB / 7950142   0.1 s       7.3 MB / 262211     
7       10  1 / 10.1.0.5    12:36:38        8.4 min     3 s     15.2 MB / 9347698   0.1 s       8.2 MB / 292230
```

based on this some tasks complete in seconds, while others take several minutes. I'm trying to rule out data skew (my group by shouldn't produce skewed data), but if this was data skew presumably the slower jobs would have a much a larger input size than the faster ones (which they don't).

Another oddity is that sever jobs (even ones which take several minutes to complete) have an input size of 0B but a non-zero input records?!

TLDR: why do some of my taks take much longer to compete than others?